# Why does Android suggest turning OFF Secure Startup?

Tags: notifications, settings, security, 7.0-nougat

I recently enabled Secure Startup on my new phone (LG V20) running on Android 7.0 Nougat. Almost immediately, the "settings suggestions" began notifying me whenever browsing in the settings that this was enabled, seemingly prompting me to turn it off. This confuses me. Having your data encrypted is a VERY GOOD thing, it makes your phone more secure. That's why it's called SECURE Startup! And now another notification is saying that On Body Detection, which keeps my phone unlocked whenever it detects that it is "on me", is NOT enabled, seemingly prompting me to turn it on!

So is Google anti-security/anti-privacy now or something???

Comment: When was Google not anti-privacy?

Comment: zing..........XD